# measuring heartbeat rate with Android device

Tags: java, android, kotlin, camera, heartbeat

How can I implement Android code to measure the heartbeat rate with the camera? I could not find any tutorials about creating an Android heartbeat monitor. I would be more than happy if you can suggest any tutorials or Github repositories that can teach how to create an  Android heartbeat monitor application.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Hi if you want to measure heart rate in android you can
visit : https://github.com/kibotu/Heart-Rate-Ometer
How It Works :https://github.com/phishman3579/android-heart-rate-monitor/wiki/How-it-works.

Requirements
JDK8
Android Build Tools 27.0.2
Android SDK 27

[This is how it looks after proper implementation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CE24b.png)

Answer (score 0):

There are two main approaches to do this task. Use the camera information as a Oximeter and measure blood flow, you can do it with the average intensity when camera is covered with finger, or you can use face and some filter like [Eulerian Magnification](https://people.csail.mit.edu/mrub/evm/) or [Optical Flow](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7132025) to extract that information.
I develop an App called [Nami - Heart Rate](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.flownami) that measure heart rate like a stethoscope, from audio stuff, and I apply the same methods with camera and the results was very good. So, the EVM method works like a charm when users keep then calm and static, with no lights or scene variations.

Comment: Thank  you  but it  seems  that  user  needs  a smartwach  to  user Nami-Heart Rate app, I need an application  that works  without wearables

Comment: You don't need smartwatch to use Nami app, but you can use with smartwatch to keep sessions recorded (I not sure anymore about this feature cause Android Wear change a lot last years and I just test with my LG Urbane that stops works long time ago) you need just smartphone's microphone to use Nami app for measure heart rate.

Comment: is it open source? if yes,  can you provide a source code link?